# JHipster AWS and default subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, jhipster

I use Jhipster in order to deploy on Amazon (jhipster aws / https://www.jhipster.tech/aws/).

I receive the following error during deploy:

```
    Create S3 bucket  
    Bucket psp-sample created successful                                                                                                                                                                    Upload WAR to S3                                                      
War uploaded successful                                               

                                                                                                                                               Create database                                                        D:\projects\sample\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31        

                throw err;                                                                                                                   
                ^                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                               Error: ERROR! No default subnet detected in VPC. Please contact AWS Support to recreate default Subnets.                                 
        at Environment.error (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:157:40)

        at module.exports.error (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:2064:18)

        at rds.createDatabase (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\aws\index.js:175:30)

        at createDbInstance (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\aws\lib\rds.js:36:33)

        at Response.rds.createDBInstance (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\aws\lib\rds.js:124:13)

        at Request.<anonymous> (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:364:18)  

        at Request.callListeners (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:109:20)

        at Request.emit (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:81:10)

        at Request.emit (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)  

        at Request.transition (D:\projects\sample\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
```

I understand that I need a default subnet and I cannot do this myself without AWS support
(https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=240833).

Is there another way to specify the VPC and not use the default one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a subnet in each zone and this solved my problem.